# Implementing an API versioning system

Tags: php, api

Hello I have the following API controller:

```
v3
```

with the following api functions

```
buy
list
delete
edit
```

Someone can go to http://example.com/v3/buy/ and access api functions above.

I also do parameter checking in v3 controller before I call the api functions to make sure the right params are passed in.

I am implementing backward incompatible changes. What is the best way to properly implement versioning?

I was thinking about doing the following:
 having separate functions for each version like

```
buy_v1
buy_v2
```

Each function in the controller returns responses of models functions.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a new controller called v4. You could abstract your methods into helper classes (or a superclass) and just keep one version of the code for each different method. Gives you solid code reuse.

Comment: There might be tons of versions though. Like 20 new versions.

Comment: You should only ever have to add a new controller if you're implementing new backwards-incompatible functions, and even then, you'd only have to override the previous class. If the new versions of the methods are designed to work like an overloaded function, then I'd have all the different possibilities map to the same endpoint then check for correct sets of values